# Installing all the correct versions of packages when handed over a new code base?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, build-dependencies

So i was handed over someones code base, just a zip file with a visual studio solution but it doesn't build. Just has a few hundred errors 'Type or namespace name x could not be found.' When i look at 'Manage packages for solution...' all of the packages are installed and it says the version of each one. Do I have to restore the packages? Reinstall the correct version of each one independently? How do I go about getting this solution to build on my machine? Thanks.

Comment: you might not be having package or dll referred

Comment: likely yes to restoring the packages. if you have the packages config then by all means restore.

Comment: There is a packages.config and theyre all in there, but I've tried Restore Nuget Packages and it finishes immediately saying there is nothing to restore

Comment: welcome to what's known as "DLL HELL"  if you look at the right side of the solution explorer you should see yellow warning icons on each project, dig into those and manually install the missing packages

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 Thank you this is the problem. Well this should be fun...

Comment: @nsquires glad to help, been there many many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to what's known as "DLL HELL" if you look at the right side of the solution explorer you should see yellow warning icons on each project, dig into those and manually install the missing packages –